# Laravel 8 adding data to pivot table with seeder using factory

Tags: laravel

I have Product and Category model and I've crated a many to many relationships with a pivot table named category_product.

I have also created 2 factories for category and product.

I am trying to add 100 products with 2 categories for each. Somehow it ads 200 records to my categories table. What I am doing wrong?

My CategoryFactory class:

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 12),
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];
}
```

And my ProductFactory class is looking like that:

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->faker->name,
        'description' => $this->faker->text,
        'image' => 'image-' . rand(1, 10) . '.jpg',
        'price' => $this->faker->numberBetween(300, 20000),
        'code' => $this->faker->regexify('[A-Z0-9]{12}'),
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];
}
```

I have these in my ProductSeeder

```
Product::factory(100)->has(Category::factory()->count(2))->create();
```

My pivot table migration:

```
Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained();
    $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your factory seeder, you are essentially saying "*for every product, create two new categories, and then link them to the product*", which is why you are ending up with 200 categories. If you look in your pivot table, you'll see you also have 200 entries, but no category_id will be the same.

If, I am assuming, you want 100 products, 2 categories and a linkage between them, your seeder should be more like

```
$categories= Category::factory()->count(2)->create();

$products = Product::factory()
        ->count(100)
        ->hasAttached($categories)
        ->create();
```

You'll end up with 100 products, 2 categories, and 200 pivot entries where the category_id has a cardinality of 2 (i.e. ids 1 and 2)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It still adds 2 records to my categories table with a random number between 1 and 12.

Comment: Can you expand on your comment? You have more than 2 entries in your categories table at the end?

Comment: I have a seeder for categories also but even I commented out all lines product seeder adds 2 records to categories table. In the name column there is a random number for each record.

Comment: I think the problem is related to category factory.